# Regular expression in vb.net not working

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to make work my regular expression. It should accept only alphanumeric with a coma and apostrophe. They can be put in any order. I have created a method that would only accept the accepted characters. It seems like its rejecting the characters that I only want to be accepted. Here is the code:

```
Public Shared Function formatToken_alphanumericWithSpecificSymbol(input As String) As String

    Dim pattern As String = "^[\w', ]+$"
    Dim rgx As Regex = New Regex(pattern)
    Dim mInput As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

    For Each c As Char In input

        If rgx.IsMatch(c.ToString()) Then
        Else
            mInput.Append(c)
        End If
    Next

    Return mInput.ToString()

End Function
```

it is suppose to return all of the characters accepted only. Example if abc'* is passed: it should return only abc'

Comment: What is that code supposed to do? `"^[\w', ]+$"` matches any string containing 1+ word, `'`, `,` and space chars. It seems all you need is `If rgx.IsMatch(input) Then Return input`

Comment: it is suppose to return all of the characters only. Example if abc'* is passed: it should return only abc'

Comment: @War10ck  the `\w` means word characters which would include alphanumeric chars [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#WordCharacter)

Comment: @Justgfather  Get rid of the `ELSE` statement, you are reversing your if.  However this is an inefficient solution when the regex can be run accross the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to filter out the illegal characters you can do this.

```
Dim pattern As String = "[^\w', ]"
Dim rgx As Regex = New Regex(pattern)
Return rgx.Replace(input, "")
```

To return if a string is valid

```
Dim pattern As String = "^[\w', ]+$"
Dim rgx As Regex = New Regex(pattern)
Return rgx.IsMatch(input)
```

Just to comment on your implementation, the reason your code is not working is that you are only appending the characters in the `ELSE` condition, remove the else and it would work.  However as the regex can operate on the entire solution you should let it rather than parse each character individually yourself.

Comment: i want to return a new string

Comment: @Justgfather The first answer will do that rgx.Replace returns a new string - it doesn't alter input